# ConTeXt: Curl apostrophe entity (&apos;)

Tags: context, typography, apostrophe

## Background

A Markdown document is converted to XHTML. The XHTML document encodes quotation marks and apostrophes using named entities, such as `&ldquo;` and `&apos;`.

Note: Cross-posted to the mailing list, in case this is a regression.

Version: 2022.09.11 20:44

## Problem

The apostrophes are output as straight quotes, rather than curled quotes. This is surprising because (a) it was working in a previous version; and (b) the other entities are output as expected, shown here:

[image: straight apostrophe]

## Code

Here's an example:

```tex
\xmltexentity{apos}{’}
\xmltexentity{lsquo}{‘}
\xmltexentity{rsquo}{’}
\xmltexentity{laquo}{«}
\xmltexentity{raquo}{»}

\startbuffer[document]
<body>
  &lsquo;Sylvia&apos;s spilled &laquo;wine&raquo;.&rsquo;
</body>
\stopbuffer

\startxmlsetups xml:xhtml
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{body}{xml:*}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:body
  \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregistersetup{xml:xhtml}

\starttext
  \xmlprocessbuffer{xhtml}{document}{}
\stoptext
```

The following code helps further demonstrate the issue:

```tex
\xmltexentity{apos}{AP:’}
\xmltexentity{lsquo}{LQ:‘}
\xmltexentity{rsquo}{’:RQ}
```

Produces:

[image: left/right quotes]

I'd expect to see `AP:` in the text before the apostrophe, in addition to curling it.

## Question

How do you curl the apostrophe character entity (`&apos;`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do you curl the apostrophe character entity (')?

You can add

```tex
\definefontfeature[default][default][trep=yes]
```

to the start of your document.

> in case this is a regression.

In some sense, it's a regression since something that used to work now doesn't, but [according to Hans this is now the intended behaviour](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2021/104301.html). I personally think that `trep=yes` should still be the default, but I can also understand not wanting to modify the input files by default.

> I'd expect to see AP: in the text before the apostrophe, in addition to curling it.

It appears that ConTeXt won't let you redefine any predefined entities. Running:

```tex
\enabletrackers[xml.entities]

\xmltexentity{apos}{XXX}
\xmltexentity{lsquo}{YYY}
\xmltexentity{rsquo}{ZZZ}
\xmltexentity{laquo}{«}
\xmltexentity{raquo}{»}
```

gives you

```
xml             > tex > registering tex entity 'apos' as 'XXX'
xml             > tex > registering tex entity 'lsquo' as 'YYY'
xml             > tex > registering tex entity 'rsquo' as 'ZZZ'
xml             > tex > registering tex entity 'laquo' as '«'
xml             > tex > registering tex entity 'raquo' as '»'
xml             > core > resolving entity &lsquo; to internal ''
xml             > core > resolving entity &lsquo; to internal ''
xml             > core > resolving entity &apos; to predefined '''
xml             > core > resolving entity &laquo; to internal ''
xml             > core > resolving entity &laquo; to internal ''
xml             > core > resolving entity &raquo; to internal ''
xml             > core > resolving entity &raquo; to internal ''
xml             > core > resolving entity &rsquo; to internal ''
xml             > core > resolving entity &rsquo; to internal ''
xml             > tex > passing entity 'lsquo' as 'YYY' using 'ctxcatcodes'
xml             > tex > passing entity 'U+27' as ''' using 'ctxcatcodes'
xml             > tex > passing entity 'laquo' as '«' using 'ctxcatcodes'
xml             > tex > passing entity 'raquo' as '»' using 'ctxcatcodes'
xml             > tex > passing entity 'rsquo' as 'ZZZ' using 'ctxcatcodes'
```

You can "fix" this by changing line 189 of `texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/lxml-tab.lua` from

```lua
        resolve_predefined = settings.resolve_predefined_entities -- in case we have escaped entities
```

to

```lua
        resolve_predefined = false -- in case we have escaped entities
```

then run `context --make`. This "fixes" the problem, but you really **shouldn't do this** since modifying the base files is a pretty bad idea. There's probably a proper way to set this value to `false`, although I'm not too sure how.